# Building a REST JSON API with Laravel

Tags: php, json, api, rest, laravel

I need to build a mobile version of my application. The mobile app is going to have the same functionality and for this I need to build an API for my web application that can be accessed from the mobile client.

Let's have an example: I have a controller class called `PostController` that is responsible for the posts in the application. This is a resource controller.

```
Route::resource("users.posts", "PostController");
```

When the user access `http://domain.com/users/{id}/posts/{id}`, he gets a rendered HTML response. This is done in the `PostController@show` method:

```
public function show($user_id, $post_id) {
    $post = Post::findOrFail($post_id);
    // other logic here

    return view("post.show", ["post" => $post_id]);
}
```

But now the user launches his mobile application which queries `http://api.domain.com/users/{id}/posts/{id}`. I know I could create a separate controller for the API, but this would result to code duplication. Hard to maintain, not a clever idea.

How do I make a JSON API that takes advantage of the existing controllers?

Maybe something like

```
public function show($user_id, $post_id) {
    $post = Post::findOrFail($post_id);
    // other logic here

    if(is api.domain.com) {
        return json
    } else {
        return view("post.show", ["post" => $post_id]);
    }

}
```

I need to secure the API with OAuth and I have used the [oauth2-server-laravel](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel) package.

Comment: You seem to have it figured out already.. what's your question?

Comment: @BrianGlaz I have this idea of how to do it, but I have no idea if it's any good (read: is this the way it should be done)  or how to actually do it. As you can see, I only have some dummy content in the last snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It's primarily personal preference, I would use separate controllers because I see an api and the web app as separate applications.

Comment: This could have been a comment. Please provide solutions in your answer.